# Unable to merge dex with LinkedIn SDK added into project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk, linkedin-api

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

```
 multiDexEnabled true
```

I have included multiDexEnabled true and also am using Gradle version 3.0.0

The error happens only when i integrate LinkedIn SDK into my app its showing !

If i remove LinkedIn SDK the error is not coming !

am using Android Studio 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

1. From the Build `menu` -> press the `Clean Project` button.
2. When task completed, press the `Rebuild Project` button from the Build menu